# JVM heap size issues

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I am just started R&D on JVM heap size and observed some strange behavior.

- My system RAM size is 4 GB
- OS is 64-bit windows 7
- Java version is 1.7

Here is the observations:

I wrote a sample main program which starts & immediately went to **wait** state.

When I run the program from ***eclipse*** with **-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m** parameters it can able to run 3 times/parallel-process from eclipse i.e. 3 parallel process only as my RAM is 4GB only. This is expected behavior.

Hence I had rerun the same with **-Xms512m -Xmx512m** parameters and it can able to run 19 times/parallel-process from eclipse even my RAM is 4GB. HOW?

I used **VisualVM** tool to cross-check and I can see 19 process ids and each process id is allocated with **512m** even my RAM size is 4GB, but HOW?

I have goggled it & gone through lot oracle documentation about the Memory management & optimization but those articles not answered my question.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Baji

Comment: Goggle told me a computer can swap RAM to virtually create more RAM memory by freeing the bits it doesn't use *right then*.

Comment: If so, it should consistent in the above both the cases but behavior is different.

Comment: Are you sure that all processes were started in parallel?

Comment: yes, when I run with -Xms512m -Xmx512m parameters it started 19 process in parllel. 

I have cross verified with VisualVM tool which shows me all the 19 process ids and each allocated 512M

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you couldn't start more than 3 processes with -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M. I tested it on my 4GB Linux system, and I could start at least 6 such processes; I didn't try to start more.

Anyway, this is due to the fact that the program doesn't actually use that memory if you just start it with -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M. These just specify the maximum size of the heap. If you don't allocate that amount of data, this memory won't get actually used then.

"top" shows the virtual set size to be more than 1024M for such processes, but it isn't actually using that memory. It has just allocated address space but never used it.

Comment: Hey! Juhist,Thanks for the quick update.

So, is it mean you can start even 100 processes with -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M? when your program actually not using any data/memory.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to start even 100 processes. Or I'm not that sure about it, depends on how much memory the JVM uses for processes that don't require any additional memory. But you should at least be able to start at least tens of processes even with -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M in your 4GB environment.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. But still I can able to start 3 process only with -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M in your 4GB windows 7 environment.

Comment: Have you tried running the command from the command-line instead of from Eclipse? What is the actual error message you get? I don't have Windows and Eclipse and Java 1.7 installed, just Linux command-line and the standard JVM 1.6. But you should find the java.exe somewhere and start using c:\path\to\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M cl.as.s

Answer (score 0):

The actual memory in your PC and the memory that is allocated must not match each other. In fact your operating system is moving data from the RAM ontothe hdd when your ram is full. This is called swapping / Ram-paging.
Thats why windows has the swap-file on the hdd and unix has a swap partition.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the inputs.

If so, why it was not allowed to run more than 3 times/process in case of -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m? whereas it allows 19 process with -Xms512m -Xmx512m even I have 4 GB RAM?